# How to import and save in Matlab Multiple Text Files creating a Matrix for each files

Tags: matlab, file, text, import

I have a very large data set which is divided in folders, I have 100 folders with approximately 200 text files each. I have been trying the for loop first of all importing one and then in another command importing the rest. But I am not interested in a dataarray but rather conserving each file with its name as I have to then match the dates among all the files and each file does not have the same amount of columns.

Each text file has is like the one I have attached, where the data I need is from the row 23 until column 13.

The data names are saves as 010010.txt, 010030.txt, 010050.txt ......until 014957.txt , they are not sequential

Apart from this I have created a script for importing one file but I would like to know how to repeat the same script for the rest.

```
filename = 'C:*\010010.txt';

startRow = 22;

formatSpec = '%4f%6f%6f%6f%6f%6f%6f%6f%6f%6f%6f%6f%6f%[^\n\r]';

fileID = fopen(filename,'r');

dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', '', 'WhiteSpace', '', 'HeaderLines' ,startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError', false);

fclose(fileID);

Untitled (010010) = [dataArray{1:end-1}];
```

I would like to repeat the same import process but for the rest files. I would appreciate any suggestion

The text files have the following format:

I only need from row 23 and column 13 and each txt file has different number of rows as some have data from 1992 - 2014 and other have only 2000 - 2014. The first column is the year and column 2 to 13 are months.

Comment: How do you plan to generate the filenames if the numbers in the filenames are not sequential? How do you know what the filenames/directory names are?

Comment: So you recommend first changing the filenames into a sequential format? any idea how to do that for 7000 files...

Comment: No. My question is how you would know which filename to use. You have to use a loop of some kind to load them and create the filename dynamically. If the filenames/directories are just random numbers, how do you know which random number to pick? You can't just pick any and hoping that it is a valid file. There must be some kind of pattern in the file/directory names...? Otherwise, how would you know what files/directories to look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you know the basepath under which all your folders are. You can then use something like this:

```
% First find all folders
folders = cell(0);                              % empty cell to save folder names
nFolders = 0;
allFolders = ls(basePath);                      % find all files and folders
for k=1:size(allFolders,1)
    curFolder = fullfile(basePath,strtrim(allFolders(k,:)));
    if isdir(curFolder)                         % find out if it is a folder
        if ~(allFolders(k,1) == '.')            % ignore '.' and '..'
            folders{nFolders+1,1} = curFolder;  % Save folder path
            nFolders = nFolders + 1;         
        end
    end
end

% Then find all files inside these folders
files = cell(0);                               % empty cell array for file names
nFiles = 0;
for k=1:nFolders                               % go through all folders
    allFiles = ls(folders{k,1});
    for l=1:size(allFiles,1)                   % go through all found files/subfolders
        curFile = fullfile(folders{k},strtrim(allFiles(l,:)));
        if ~isdir(curFile)                     % only select files
            files{nFiles+1,1} = curFile;       % and save it to the cell
            nFiles = nFiles + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Now you can iterate through the `files` cell and read all files according to your script. I see you are interested in the file name. You can extract the file name by

```
[path,filename,extension] = fileparts(files{k,1});
```

To import text files, you can use `dlmread`, which I think is more intuitive than `textscan` (but has more limitations, of course). For that you don't have to open the file using `fopen`, you can directly supply the file name.

```
value = dlmread(fileName,' ',[23,13,23,13]);
```

The delimiter is now a white space and only the value at row=23 / col=13 is read. Note that the range starts at row/col=0, not 1 like normally in Matlab - so maybe you'll have to change it to `[22,12,22,12]`.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. One more question what about including format specifications when importing because the text files have headers and I only want to import from row 23

Comment: I added a possible solution with `dlmread`. Hope this works for you.

Comment: It all working good!! I only still have a few issues first how can I move from folder to folder and the second one is how can I conect the two last rows of code in all the above script

Comment: Any idea of How to Use Textscan for Multiple Importing?